# Browser Back button should work same as Back button in my form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a `.net core web application` which has multiple screens, every screen has `2 submit buttons(1 is the Back button and the other is next button)` like below.

```
<input name="back" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" type="submit" value="Back" formnovalidate formaction="BackToIncidentInfo?tabId=@Model.TabId">
<input name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The above `Back button` will act as:

When the user enters some info and click on `Back button` all the entered info will be saved and user will be redirected back to the previous page.

My requirement here is:
The `Browser Back button` should act same as `Back button` in the page.
Mean, when the user clicks on `Form Back button` Since I am using `beginform` and the `back button type="submit"` I am able to get the formfields and based on that I am saving that info.
I am not sure how to achieve this when user clicks on `Browser back button`.

Please help me out....

Till now I tried using `window.onpopstate()`, but the issue here is, it is triggering when the `page loads`, `when user clicks on browser back and when we click browser forward...`

```
I want to catch the exact event only when the user clicks Browser Back button...
```

My intention of solving this issue is:

inside the `browser back event` I would like to find a back button and make a click function which would achieve my task.. as below:

```
$('input[name="back"]').click();
```

So my problem here is only to detect the Browser back button event.

Comment: I believe with the browser BACK button that is history based. You cannot make it submit the content of the page. You could however detect the attempt to navigate from the page and prompt the user to use the form buttons and not the browser buttons instead in order to request the user to submit the content.

Comment: Can you add http referrer in the back button href ?

Comment: @Ajith I did not get you